# Memoize over one parameter

Tags: clojure, memoization

I have a function which takes two inputs which I would like to memoize. The output of the function only depends on the value of the first input, the value of the second input has no functional effect on the outcome (but it may affect how long it takes to finish). Since I don't want the second parameter to affect the memoization I cannot use `memoize`. Is there an idiomatic way to do this or will I just have to implement the memoization myself?

Comment: Can you share an example (even contrived) of your function?

Comment: If this is the case, you're basically saying the "extra" argument does not influence the result—so why does your function require it? You could make a function that takes only the argument that _does_ matter, memoize it, and call it from a function that also takes the arg that _doesn't_ matter.

Comment: It's a search function, the first input defines a goal and the second a starting point. While the search will always eventually find the goal, the time it takes could be reduced if the starting point happens to be close. So in a sense the second arg does matter since it may reduce the search time.

Comment: This might be totally left-field since I just woke up, but given your last comment, it might make sense to lazily do the search, return the lazy results, then take the starting position into consideration later in a different function. If the second parameter only ever has the effect of changing the execution time, it doesn't seem like it actually has anything to do with the operation of the function, which suggests that the function is doing too much.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I had same thought, would help to see actual code

Comment: @OParry I'll just throw this out there: if you put together a working complete solution using a memoization technique suggested here and post it to Code Review, I would (along with others here I'm sure) be interested in doing a review of it to suggest a different way. You have your memoization answer here, but as I mentioned above, I suspect there's a better way of going about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend using a cache (like [clojure.core.cache](https://github.com/clojure/core.cache/wiki/Using)) for this instead of function memoization:

```
(defonce result-cache
  (atom (cache/fifo-cache-factory {})))

(defn expensive-fun [n s]
  (println "Sleeping" s)
  (Thread/sleep s)
  (* n n))

(defn cached-fun [n s]
  (cache/lookup
    (swap! result-cache
           #(cache/through
              (fn [k] (expensive-fun k s))
              %
              n))
    n))

(cached-fun 111 500)
Sleeping 500
=> 12321
(cached-fun 111 600) ;; returns immediately regardless of 2nd arg
=> 12321
(cached-fun 123 600)
Sleeping 600
=> 15129
```

Answer (score 2):

`memoize` doesn't support caching only on some args, but's pretty easy to make it yourself:

```
(defn search* [a b]
  (* a b))

(def search
  (let [mem (atom {})]
    (fn [a b]
      (or (when-let [cached (get @mem a)]
            (println "retrieved from cache")
            cached)
          (let [ret (search* a b)]
            (println "storing in cache")
            (swap! mem assoc a ret)
            ret)))))
```

Comment: I think this simple approach is preferable if all your cached results fit comfortably in memory, don't need eviction policy, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap you function into another function (with one parameter) and call it the function with second default parameter. Then you can memoize the new function.

```
(defn foo
  [param1]
  (baz param1 default-value))
```

Comment: Thing is, woulden't that mean that every time I wanted to change the value of the second argument I would loose all the previous memoization data?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are not able to natively memoize those two arguments, but you could use `partial` instead to take fewer than the normal arguments to your function. You won't be caching it's execution but that may be helpful if you need to pre-load some function parameters:

An example:

```
(defn sum [a b]
   (+ a b))

(def partial-sum (partial sum 2))
(partial-sum 3) ;; returns 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom memoize function. For example
`(defn memoize-first [f]`
 `(let [cache (atom {})]`
  `(fn [x]`
   `(if-let [cached-result (get @cache x)]`
   `cached-result`
  `(let [result (f x)]`
  `(swap! cache assoc result)`
 `result))))`
`(defn your-function []`
  `;;`
`)`

`(def memoized-function (memoize-first your-function))`